# PostgreSQL Create Sequence using new id

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a sequence for each row created in the table account, like os_1, os_2, etc...

How can I get the id of this new row and insert it on the name of the sequence?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_os_seq() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    #variable_conflict use_variable
    BEGIN
        --CREATE SEQUENCE seqname;
        EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE os_', NEW.id);
        return NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER create_os_seq AFTER INSERT ON account FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_os_seq();
```

Table account

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
nane VARCHAR
```

After creating a sequence i´ll put its number in the OS table

table os

```
id INT
account_id INT
```

Comment: A sequence for each **row**? Why would you want to do that? Why do you think you would need a million sequences? Or a hundred million?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume you want to take care of self incrementing values?.. Postgres uses [shortcut](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) `SERIAL` instead of `AUTO_INCREMENT`, just create table like:

```
CREATE TABLE so79 (id bigserial primary key, col text);
```

That will automatically create sequence for you and assign its value as default for column id. Basically will make it smth like `AUTO_INCREMENT`. You don't have to use trigger to increment values...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that creating a sequence for each *row* is a good idea. Instead, tell us what you're trying to do.

My guess is you need a waterline indicator, a high point you intend to increment on some action. Just use an integer.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  foo_id     serial,
  max_seen   int
);
```

Now you can do whatever with triggers on other tables and such to increment `max_seen`.